Calling a Java or C# program from RPGLE on IBM iSeries AS400
I am trying to determine if C# can be called from a CLP on the AS400 or if we are limited to only Java.
Our IT department is looking into our options on a REWRITE project that will be replacing RPG programs on our legacy system.  We will be using a ODBC connection for IBM db2, AS400 and would prefer to utilize C# classes for our new programs.   I am able to find steps to guide the process for using a CL call from AS400 for a Java class, but can this also be done with a C# class?   I wasn't able to find information pertaining to a C# compiling to iSeries either.  Is there support to integrate C# with iSeries programs?

Wikipedia says the AS400 was discontinued a decade ago. What OS is the computer running? A decade ago, .NET was Windows only (or struggle with Mono if you wanted cross platform).

As long as you are really running IBM i on Power vs. AS400 or iSeries, this article indicates that it should be possible to use C# for your application: https://www.itjungle.com/2019/03/13/building-out-the-net-stack-around-mono-for-ibm-i/. However, it might be better to use a language that is supported directly by IBM for anything mission critical.
Java on the other hand is directly supported by IBM on IBM i, iSeries, and even AS400 (though you can't get any support these days for the much older iSeries and AS400 platforms).

Regarding calling Java methods from RPGLE - everything is in the documentation.
I've never heard of C#.
If you work with a database and also perform some commercial calculations, there is no point in switching to Java - you will lose a lot in productivity and resource efficiency.
Unlike Java, RPGLE allows you to work effectively in the database not only through built-in SQL, but also directly (and in some cases this is many times faster - in my personal practice I had an example when the fact that an SQL query was done in 7 hours, being implemented on RPGLE with direct access to the database runs for 15 minutes).
In addition, RPGLE natively supports all data types that are in the database - you do not need to waste time creating wrapper objects for types such as decimal, numeric, date, time, timestamp.
RPGLE is specially designed to solve this class of problems such as working with databases and commercial calculations. And for these tasks it is good - better than any other general-purpose language. And it is not legacy at all - it is constantly evolving and something new and useful is constantly appearing there.
I myself have been writing only in C/C++ for 25 years (and now I sometimes write in them). But for solving problems related to the implementation of complex business logic and intensive work with databases in highly loaded systems, I like RPGLE much better.

If your project will be using c# with ODBC to access Db2 on "AS400", I would say that it is a flawed project in itself, because it implies moving logic out of server passing through the ODBC filter. Maybe this project have more restrictions not explained here: may be your "legacy" AS400 is a real one, running some flavour of 5.x OS version, out of support, planned to migrate to some another platform. Please let us know more about your restrictions. AS400 evolved to 7.x versions, and currently have several native ways to modernize, including RPG also.
